# How to wrap BeautifulSoup find statements into a function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing some BeautifulSoup code to populate a dictionary from the results of an html page, and I need some error handling.  While what I have does the job I feel like there is a better way of doing it.  Here is what I have:

```
    rightcol = result.find("div", {"class":"rightcol"})

    try: mydict['rating'] = rightcol.find("div", {"class":"rating"}).contents[1]['class']
    except AttributeError: pass

    try: mydict['reviews'] = rightcol.find("span", {"class":"reviews"}).contents
    except AttributeError: pass

    try: mydict['address'] = rightcol.find("address").contents
    except AttributeError: pass

    (10+ more statements of the same kind)
```

What I am hoping to do is put the error handling into a function, something like:

```
    def process(key, code):
        try: mydict[key] = (execute the BeautifulSoup code, different for each function call)
        except: pass
```

However, I'm not sure of the syntax of how to pass the BeautifulSoup instructions to the function.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put functions in a `dict` and call them whenever you need them:

```
def hello(name):
    return 'Hello, ' + name

funcMap = {'greet' : hello}

greeting = funcMap['greet']('Peter')
print greeting # Hello, Peter
```

You can do something very similar for this code here.